# Java Swing Panel not show added component

Tags: java, swing, camera

I am using  the `SARXOS` Webcam api and
I coding simple `java swing qr code` scanner by web cam but not view  camera screen to panel.

```
public class WebCamQRCode extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable, ThreadFactory {

    /**
     * Creates new form WebCamQRCode
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6441489157408381878L;

    private Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(this);

    private Webcam webcam = null;
    private WebcamPanel panel = null;

    public WebCamQRCode() {
        initComponents();
        privateinitComponents();

    }

    public void privateinitComponents() {

        setTitle("Read QR With Webcam");

        Dimension size = new Dimension(640, 480);

        webcam = Webcam.getWebcams().get(0);
        webcam.setViewSize(size);

        panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
        panel.setPreferredSize(size);

        photopanel.add(panel);

        photopanel.setVisible(true);

        executor.execute(this);
    }
```

Codes run correctly and `scan qr image` but not view camera screen panel

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that initComponents() is the autogenerated Netbeans function. If this is correct,  it lays out components and then calls pack(). Changing the layout after this has returned usually does not work. The better approach for using the Netbeans GUI builder is to select the photopanel in the Design view and right-click for popup menu and choose "Customize Code" then paste the code you have here for privateinitComponents into the CustomCode dialog so it gets called before the outer frame is packed. Also you need to check and possibly resize photopanel.